# Is there a connection between MaxAuthorities from authority_discovery, babe and grandpa?

Tags: babe, grandpa

All three pallets (babe, grandpa, and authority_discovery) have a field known as `MaxAuthorities`. For a chain, should these values all point to the same number or can they be different?

From AuthorityDiscovery docs :

> type MaxAuthorities

```
The maximum number of authorities that can be added.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory they could be different as each pallet's implementation could differ, but I would set them all to the same value. In kusama/polkadot we set them all to 100,000 at the moment (not that we have that many validators).

For parachains you would want to set this to the max number of collators you could have. For example Acala is doing this at the moment:

```
type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
```

Answer (score 5):

Well yes they could be different if you want Babe Authorities to be different from Grandpa Authorities, but this just puts more capital requirements on your consensus system so probably best to make them all the same value and use pallet-session to manage your authority set